# Error upgrading Grails app from 3.1.10 to 3.2.5

Tags: grails, spring-boot, database-migration

I'm trying to upgrade my Grails app from 3.1.10 to 3.2.5, to use new GORM etc, but startup fails when reaching database-migrations.

I get:

```
    INFO 2/9/17 2:08 PM: liquibase: Can not use class org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.liquibase.GormDatabase as a Liquibase service because it does not have a no-argument constructor
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is rolled back; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Transaction is already completed - do not call commit or rollback more than once per transaction
at org.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:183)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150)
at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$execute.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationTransactionManager.withTransaction(DatabaseMigrationTransactionManager.groovy:31)
at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationTransactionManager$withTransaction.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin$_doWithApplicationContext_closure2.doCall(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2015)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2068)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$164.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:63)
at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:523)
at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doPostProcessing(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:224)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:246)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at saasapi.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Transaction is already completed - do not call commit or rollback more than once per transaction
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:704)
at org.grails.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.commit(MultiTransactionStatus.java:73)
at org.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:156)
... 56 common frames omitted
```

I have updated or added to my build.gradle the following dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ....
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.4"
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.1.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.1.Final"
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'
    compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.3'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb'
}
```

People have seen liquibase error "PM: liquibase: Can not use class org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.liquibase.GormDatabase as a Liquibase service because it does not have a no-argument constructor" previously in these Github issues:

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/issues/81

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/issues/64#issuecomment-256739113

But for them it wasn't a breaking error.

When I tried to update to Grails 3.2.3, then I also saw that liquibase error message, but otherwise everything else worked (migration logs were also not visible). Maybe the problem lies there, that Grails 3.2.3 uses Spring Boot 1.4.1, but Grails 3.2.5 uses Spring Boot 1.4.4.

Anyways I'm lost and I'm hoping that somebody can help me.

EDIT: I used database-migrations plugin to set up my database tables and I'm using it for changing it now as well. Also I have enabled database-migrations on startup.

**EDIT2: It seems that the problem itself is not so much related to database migrations**

I use multiple datasources (relevant parts from application.yml):

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        dbCreate: none
        properties:
            testOnBorrow: true
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
    myOtherDataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
        dbCreate: none

environments:
    development:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_default_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true
                username: my_user
                password: my_pass
            myOtherDataSource:
                driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
                url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_other_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
                username: my_user
                password: my_pass
```

Also I can start my app, when there's no database migrations at startup, but then I get different errors related to db:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - PooledConnection has already been closed.
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - SQLException occurred when processing request: [GET] /my-endpoint
......
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1934)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.listForCriteria(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:700)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.list(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:690)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder.invokeQuery(FindAllByFinder.java:54)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder$1.doInSession(FindAllByFinder.java:48)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:318)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFinder.execute(AbstractFinder.java:42)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder.doInvokeInternal(FindAllByFinder.java:45)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:174)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:374)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:169)
.....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
... 66 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an issue for this, with an example application reproducing this behaviour: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10477

**[Update]:**

I finally figured it out. Grails will create a platformtransactionmanager for each configuration under dataSources and one for the default dataSource. In your example this looks like [dataSource,myOtherDataSource,dataSource]. This is obviously not what should happen. In the GORM documentation is specified that you should use:

```
dataSource: 
  ..
dataSources: 
   myOtherDataSource:
```

This will work. Grails creates two platformtransactionmanagers and this is the correct behaviour.

But Databasemigration expects all datasources to be in the dataSources config block, so it can't find the default datasource. 
I've created a patch for this and will create a pullrequest for this as soon as another related bug is fixed;

Grails doesn't publish the default DataSource with the name 'dataSource' in the applicationContext in a Multi DataSource configuration. 
I've added this to the issue https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10477

**[Update 2]:**

I've created two pull requests to solve this issue:

grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/pull/123

and

grails/grails-core/pull/10478

These solved the issue on my system. I couldn't post two links because I don't have enough reputation according to stackoverflow :S

Comment: I know that Stack Overflow recommends not to thank in comments, but still, thank you for creating that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have nearly the same setup as you have and no problems by me.The most significant changes I have is that I am using 5.1.3 Final of hibernate-core and ehcache and org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.6. I don't have a mongodb dependency.

- Do you have multiple datasources?
- Does it start without running any migration file?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple different datasources. But only one is used for database-migrations. I will provide the relevant parts from my application.yml in my original post.

Yes, it does start without running migrations files. But then I get all sort of different errors related to db connections. I will provide meaningful example rows from error stacktraces in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I have the nearly same problem with Grails-3.2.5/3.2.6.
Please try Grails-3.2.4 and see the problem still occurs or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple datasources I have the same issue. It only happens on the default Datasource, it looks like the GrailsTemplate it trying to restore a previous state and failing to do so, because the transaction was committed.

```
  org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is rolled back; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Transaction is already completed - do not call commit or rollback more than once per transaction
    at org.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:183)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$execute.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationTransactionManager.withTransaction(DatabaseMigrationTransactionManager.groovy:31)
    at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationTransactionManager$withTransaction.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin$_doWithApplicationContext_closure2.doCall(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2015)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2068)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$164.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:63)
    at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:523)
    at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doPostProcessing(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:224)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:246)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at scd.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
  Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Transaction is already completed - do not call commit or rollback more than once per transaction
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:704)
    at org.grails.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.commit(MultiTransactionStatus.java:73)
    at org.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:156)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I made a small test case which didn't fail. After I copied in my domainclasses from the original project it failed again. After some trial and error I discovered that this error will occur if you have 32 or more domainclasses.